# Converting this C++ for loop into assembly language

Tags: c++, assembly

Basically what I am trying to do is convert this block of c++ & assembly into purely assembly, I am a bit confused as to how to conver the for loop and the rest into assembly, if anyone could let me know where I am going wrong that would be great.

This is the original

```
void encrypt_chars (int length, char EKey)      // Encryption Function.

{   char temp_char;                     // Char temporary store.

for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)    // Encrypt characters one at a time.
{
    temp_char = OChars [i];         // Orignal Chars.

    __asm {                         // Switch to inline assembly.

        push   eax                  
        push   ecx                  

        movzx  ecx,temp_char        
        push   ecx                  
        lea    eax,EKey             
        push   eax                  
        call   encrypt4             // Call the encryption subroutine 
        add    esp, 8                
        mov    temp_char,al         

        pop    ecx                  
        pop    eax                  
    }
    EChars [i] = temp_char;         // Store encrypted char in the encrypted chars array.
}
return;
```

Then this is my attempt at convering the c++ parts into assembly which is what I am stuggling with and would appreciate some pointers -

```
void encrypt_chars(int lengths, char EKey)  // Encryption Function.

{
    char temp_char; 
    __asm { 
    mov         dword ptr[i], 0
    jmp         encrypt_chars
    mov         eax, dword ptr[i]
    add         eax, 1
    mov         dword ptr[i], eax
    mov         eax, dword ptr[i]
    cmp         eax, dword ptr[lengths]
    jge         encrypt_chars 

    mov         eax, dword ptr[i]
    mov         cl, byte ptr[eax]
    mov         byte ptr[temp_char], cl

    push   eax                  
    push   ecx                  

    movzx  ecx,temp_char        
    push   ecx                  
    lea    eax,EKey             
    push   eax                  
    call   encrypt4             // Call the encryption subroutine 
    add    esp, 8                
    mov    temp_char,al         

    pop    ecx                  
    pop    eax                  


    mov         eax, dword ptr[i]
    mov         cl, byte ptr[temp_char]
    mov         byte ptr[eax], cl

}
return;
```

Comment: So, are you actually asking, how to implement a loop in inline asm? At the moment your *actual problem* is unclear, at least to me.

Comment: Looks like you've only converted into assembly, what exactly is it that you want? BTW, there's a missing curly bracket at the end of the assembly section in your code.

Comment: Also note, C++ compilers can produce assembly source code output, so you could compile your C++ program that way and look at what the compiler does. For example, with *gcc*, use `-S` command line switch to get assembly output.

Comment: If you want to see assembly output generated, you can try [compiler explorer](http://goo.gl/dlp1jh) as it provides the most verbose assembly

Comment: added some more on what I need to do.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an assembly example of a for loop:

```
mov R1, #5  ; This is the limit of the loop
mov R0, #0  ; R0 is the loop index, initialize the loop index variable.
loop:
  cmp R0, R1 ; Part of the compare expression in for loop.
  bge loop_exit;
;
;  The statement block for the for loop.
  inc R0   ; The increment part of the for loop
  b   loop ; Loop around to the compare part of the loop.

; First statement after the for loop
loop_exit:
```

Comment: Just a sidenote, counting down instead might save 1 extra line of comparison at the top - you would do `bz loop` instead (Branch if reached zero)

Comment: @jhtong, yes, the classic one instruction savings (microoptimization).  However, the OP's code counts up, and I was focusing on matching the OP's loop.  By the way, I've measured the savings on an ARM7 at 60 nanoseconds by not using the instruction.  There is also the ability to use conditional execution capability.